# iPhone finger size and angle pressure calculation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, c

For my project on the client side I want to create new algorithm to calculate the finger size and angle of the pressure on the screen and maybe some more details to create a unique finger thumb eventually to recognize the person according to it, I am willing to use private methods/libraries as this is not going to iTunes but used as enterprise application client/server model. 
There is the [GraphicsServices](https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/blob/master/GraphicsServices) library which gives some INFO (take a look on GSEvent.h)

Before diving in and invent the wheel, any of you did something similar? tips/tricks to share? maybe there are methods in the Objective C level to use ?

Any of you that feel that they can contribute to the matter and would like to join me(and have spare time) let me know.

As the nature of this client project heading to the underline C functions I assume experience with C will be needed.

Comment: The iphone screens doesn't react to pressure "at all". Its screen is capacitance touch unlike some other devices which are resistive. But there are private API calls that can give you the info about the touch area which you can use then to simulate pressure, i.e. when your finger presses harder, the touch area would be bigger. That's exactly what they use in hactar's sample to differentiate stylus and palm. But I am sure Apple would reject this.

Comment: Capacitive touch screens use a layer of capacitive material to hold an electrical charge; touching the screen changes the amount of charge at a specific point of contact, I assume the amount of charge can be measured ?

Comment: Reading a bit further: Signals travel from the touch screen to the processor as electrical impulses.
The processor uses software to analyze the data and determine the features of each touch. This includes size, shape and location of the affected area on the screen. That's what I need, size and shape. The question is how to measure them . which functions?